# Multi-lingual Flex app - preferred fonts for embedding specific languages

Tags: apache-flex

I work on a collaboration web app, built with Flex 3, that needs to support multiple languages.

Does anyone know which fonts are best for creating embedded font libraries for Chinese, Korean, Japanese, and Russian languages?  I know Arial Unicode MS will do the job, but I don't know if it will do the job best.

Localization alone won't solve the entire problem: chat input and display, for example, need to support multiple languages in the same textfield - anything typed in Chinese needs to display in Chinese; anything typed in English needs to display in English.

Using _sans is an option, but is far from preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Ended up going with _sans.  The only problem with that approach is that it doesn't look as nice as it could, which we decided was something we could live with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with an approach that switches TextFormat of characters based on unicode value.  So, characters in the primary language display in the preferred (embedded) font, while characters in other languages display in _sans.

This works out really nicely, but requires that you inspect every character that is added to a field, and requires you to inspect everything when a deletion occurs.  Kind of a lot of inspecting and I'm sure a textfield with a lot of content would start running into performance issues, but this is for a chat tool, so that isn't too critical of a use case.